# Use r object in tikz chunk in Rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, tikz

I'm trying to figure out to add R variables in a tikz chunk. Is there any way to achieve this.

Here is an example

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
TEXT <- 1
```

```{tikz, echo = FALSE}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) at (0,0) {$x$};
\node (y) at (3,0) {$y$};
\draw[->] (x) to node [anchor = north] {`r TEXT`} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

I would like the `r TEXT` to be replaced by whatever is in TEXT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a tikz chunk, you can just load the package yourself:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tikz}
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
TEXT <- 1
```

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) at (0,0) {$x$};
\node (y) at (3,0) {$y$};
\draw[->] (x) to node [anchor = north] {`r TEXT`} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
````

[image]

Comment: It there is a way by staying in the tikz chunk engine? Can't believe it was so simple. Thank you

Comment: What would be the advantage to use a tikz chunk?

Comment: I am no expert in Rmarkdown and bookdown, but can you still use the \@ref(fig:XX) to refer to tikz figure?

Comment: @POC You can place it in a `figure` environment and give it a label and caption. Then you can `\ref` it everywhere you like.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I am trying the same because a tikz chunk gives you the opportunity to create a HTML output (and PNG graph) in addition to PDF. I need to include an R object which contains my tikz code and have tried various ways (`r as in POC's example, but also \Sexpr{}) without success so far.